# Https routes change to http after login

Tags: laravel

I'm using latest version of Laravel (5.3 at this time) and I have a simple app, nothing fancy, no JS framework.

I use Cloudflare (free) to have HTTPS.

I can access my app with https, but right after I login, I'm redirect to the non-https version.

Is there a way to tell Laravel to redirect to https, not http, after login?

Here is my LoginController setting for information.

`protected $redirectTo = '/people';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to make web server rewrite all HTTP requests to HTTPS. Here's an example of VH config for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost some.app:80>
   ServerName some.app
   Redirect permanent / https://some.app
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost some.app:443>
    DocumentRoot "/home/project/public"
    ServerName some.app
    ServerAlias some.app
    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/server.key

    <Directory "/home/project/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll check how to do it with nginx, as I use it (handled by Forge, actually).